# Mongoose is not creating a collection on save() function

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have below schema.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const JobSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  posterId: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  title: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  location: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
}, { timestamp: true });

module.exports = mongoose.model('Job', JobSchema);
```

And I use below code to save new data to this collection.

```
const Job = require('../../models/Job');

new Job({
    posterId,
    title,
    location,
})
.save()
.then(job => {
    console.log('JOB: ', job) // consoles the newly added job to collection.
    if (job) {
        response.json({
            message: 'Job is saved successfully.',
        });
    } else {
        response.json({
            message: 'Job can not be saved at this time. Please try again later.',
        });
    }
})
.catch(error => {
    response.json(error);
});
```

The above code successfully saves new information to job collection but when I check that in mongoDB using mongodb CLI. I do not see any job collection there so it is not creating the collection. What am I doing wrong and how can I fix this?

Comment: I think you're supposed to create the collection before starting to save documents in it

Comment: No. In my other projects it works perfectly fine the way I am doing it now. There is some other problem which I am not sure about and thats why I asked here.

Comment: How do you check if the `Jobs` collection was created?

Comment: Is your app truly configured with the database credentials? or do you get errors about all connection issues? confirm that your model is loaded after a successful connection

Comment: @JeremyThille I use mongodb CLI. I use these commands. `use eon`, then I do `show collections` which shows only `users` collection but not `job` collection.

Comment: @Saeid-a I am configured with the database correctly because it is creating one collection already but it does not create this one.

Comment: What is the name of the database on the connection string?

Comment: @Minsky it is `eon`.

Comment: could you try to make a delay with `setTimeout(() => "your task here", 3000)`

Comment: can u try   
let job =   new Job({
posterId:posterId,
 title:title ,
 location:location
})
.save()

Comment: @Saeid-a it still did not work with that approach.

Comment: @VENKATESHCHAVVAKULA I tried that and it didnt work.

Comment: let job = new Job({ posterId:posterId, title:title , location:location }) 
job.save(function (err,data) {
  if (err) return handleError(err);
  // saved!
});

Comment: @VENKATESHCHAVVAKULA That didnt work either.

Comment: i found in mongoose documentation
https://mongoosejs.com/docs/models.html

Comment: @VENKATESHCHAVVAKULA They are both correct. The way I am doing it and the docs are mentioning.

Comment: try to create your model from `connection.model` instead of `mongoose.model`?

Comment: @Saeid-a I required `connection` from mongoose and did `connection.model` still didn't create the collection.

Comment: I've tested the code and it runs fine for me (saves the document). Did you check <DB>/<Collection> on Atlas or Compass which are normally easier to navigate?

Comment: @Minsky What is Atlas and Compass?

Comment: Those are UIs to access the database. If on CLI, can you include the log of `show dbs` at least?

Comment: @Minsky `show dbs` shows me the list of databases `admin   0.000GB
auth    0.000GB
config  0.000GB
eon     0.000GB
local   0.000GB`

Comment: that looks to me like you're accessing with a different user, without much privileges (may be wrong). Is the exact same URI string?